# validate time is within a given range

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, time

```
<tr>
  <td height="50"><br>
    <div class=headingbox>Expected Time</div>
    <input  class="textfill" type=time name=DPTime required autofocus
      onfocusout="upperCASE(this)" id=time name=time min="0800" 
      max="1600">
    </div>  
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am developing a web app for a shop. I want to validate time input so on-line orders can only be placed between 8am and 4pm.

If an order is made outside this time window I want to present an error message in an alert box.

Comment: Improved wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this](https://plnkr.co/edit/giNFl5ZaYn4H4Jctlr7r?p=preview). You can always compare the strings of date if they are in `HH:mm:ss` format